# trying to send form details to email with php

Tags: php, email, post, methods

I have the following form on index.php

```
<form id='login' action='form-login.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset >
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<center><label for='fname' >First name:</label>
<input type='text' name='fname' id='fname'  maxlength="50" />
<label for='lname' >Last name:</label>
<input type='lname' name='lname' id='lname' maxlength="50" />
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' /></fieldset></form></center><script type="text/javascript">
```

I would like the first and last name submitted to my email.
I have the following in form-login.php but it doesn't seem to be working.  I know if it's the right code either.

```
<?php header("Location: http://google.com");
$to = "myemail@domain.com";
$subject = "My Subject";
$fname = $_REQUEST ;
$lname = $_REQUEST ;
$headers = "From: $email";
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $fname, $lname) ;
?>
```

The redirect is working but the email is not being sent. My webhost (000webhost) supports this. I've done it in the past but I lost the code.

Comment: You're pushing the user to google before the mail is sent...

Comment: start by looking at the mail() function in the manual

Comment: @relentless — Nonsense, sending a location header doesn't happen before the request is finished and it doesn't abort the script.

Comment: @Quentin - Thanks for the info. However, isn't it a bit buggy to do the redirect first?

Comment: No, it isn't. The script won't abort just because you've started writing a response.

Comment: @relentless It's not working without the redirect either.

Comment: @Quentin - thanks. I misunderstood that. I thought it would cause issues on some servers.

Comment: `do { read the manual }` => http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php `while { $sent = mail($to, $subject, $fname, $lname); }` is invalid and will be rejected by ALL email clients. Use valid and properly formatted headers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the name of the fields when accessing `$_REQUEST`, like:

```
$fname = $_REQUEST['fname'];
$lname = $_REQUEST['lname'];
```

Comment: I've added that. Now when I click submit it returns the following error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/public_html/form-login.php on line 7

Comment: Could you post lines #6 and #7?

Comment: You're absolutely right! This is what this community is about: people asking for help, some other people posting suggestions and thoughts...